# Notify progress with flask

Tags: python, flask

I have created a Flask environment with a couple of routes (see code below).

I know how to return a response when the user sends a POST request to this route. However, as I expect computationally intense tasks, I would like to keep the user notified about the progress. How do I send a notification of the progress (a temporary notify instead of a response) with some parameters?

```
# libraries
import os
from flask import Flask, Response, request, json, url_for
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import time

# custom libraries
import test

# CORS
app     = Flask(__name__)
cors    = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# API ROUTES
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@app.route('/')
@cross_origin()
def api_root():
    return 'The server is up and running if you see this message'

@app.route('/newreport', methods = ['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def api_run():


    # Init
    resp = {
        'success': True,
        'status': 200
    }
    if request.environ is not None:
        print(request.environ)


    # ---- 0
    # Body attributes
    specs = request.json.get('specs', None)

    if not specs:
        print('/0')
        resp = {
            'success':  False,
            'status':   400,
            'message':  "Oops... something went wrong",
            'error':    "Missing attribute specs"
        }


    # ---- 1
    # Import and prepare the data
    if resp.get('success', None) == True:
        print('/1')
        resp = test.randomfunction(specs)



    # <-- REST response to client
    print(resp)
    if resp.get('success', None) == True:
        print('/success')
        respdata = resp.get('data')
        js       = json.dumps(respdata)
        resp     = Response(js, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        print('/fail')
        respdata = resp
        js       = json.dumps(respdata)
        resp     = Response(js, status=resp.get('status', 400), mimetype='application/json')
    return resp




# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the Routes and Application
app.run(host=os.getenv('IP', '0.0.0.0'),port=int(os.getenv('PORT', 8080)))
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by this 'a temporary notify instead of a response'?

I think, the following approach should be followed:

1. users starts a long computationally intense task
2. task is started and given an ID
3. server returns: 'task started' and the ID
4. user sends AJAX request using the task id for the progress status of the task